Efficient way to find ERC20 token contract deployments in a given time range
Given a time range, say in last 24 hours, I want to get the list of all ERC20 compatible contracts deployed efficiently.
Currently, only two ways I can think of are:

scan through all transactions and see if address ('to') is an ERC20 contract.
Scan through all ERC20 transfer events(fetched via etherscan api) and filter events with 'from' as Null. (for most such contracts, first transaction is usually minting of tokens i.e ERC20 Transfer event from Null to some recipient address.)

However, I find both above approaches inefficient. Is there a better approach?
I don't mind using a third party solution.
